# Can't convert to int32

Tags: c#, int32

I have this line of code that should convert a label and a textbox to int32 and then subtract them with eachother...

`retur = Convert.ToInt32(pengarTxtbox.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(kostarLbl.Text);`

retur is a int aswell.

This line gives me the error: Input string was not in a correct format. (I've never recived this error before)

WHY?! Am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like you forget to use `.Text` properties of your labels. But what are their values and what is your `CurrentCulture` exactly?

Comment: their input is whatever the user inputs in the UI

Comment: @Raging I don't think so, this isn't how Stack Overflow works. You can't just edit your question and make *fundamental changes* to the question you're asking. The edits invalidate all of the existing answers as well. That tells you it's a bad edit.

Comment: So roll the edit back, @Raging. I don't think it's worth the effort, so I didn't do it myself. It looks like at least 2 other people agree with you though. I don't have a vested interest here, my answer isn't one of the ones that would be invalidated. But I'm not going to take action that I disagree with. If the asker has a new question, he should post a new question.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `Text` property to get the content of the Textbox and Label.

Try This:

```
retur = Convert.ToInt32(pengarTxtbox.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(kostarLbl.Text);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are **not** passing `string` to [Convert.ToInt32(string value)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx) rather passing the control itself i.e `TextBox` and `Label`. You have to use `Text` property to get the text in the `Textbox` and `Label`.

```
retur = Convert.ToInt32(pengarTxtbox.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(kostarLbl.Text);
```